# Unit testing the safe-bool idiom

Tags: c++, unit-testing, safe-bool-idiom

To which unit tests should a class be submitted to guarantee it has all the properties required by the C++ safe-bool idiom?

Trying to name all of them (extracted from [The Safe Bool Idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html)), for an instance `test` of a class `Test` which supposedly implements the safe-bool idiom, it should **enable** the following constructs:

- `if (test) { /* test is valid */ }`
- `if (!test) { /* test is not valid */ }`

...and **disallow** the following constructs:

- `test << 1;`
- `int i = test;`
- `delete test;`
- `if (test1 == test2) {}`
- `if (test != test2) {}`

Comment: Incidentally, with `c++11` just have an `explicit operator bool()` which can't be converted without you saying so except where it is "*contextually
converted to `bool`*" (i.e. `if`, `?:`, `&&`, `||`).

Comment: The reason I want to test the safe-bool idiom is that I want to apply it to a shared_ptr's class of my own. Moreover, the reason why I implementing my own version of shared_ptr is that, because my compiler is really old, the standard library version is not available and the boost one is not compatible with the eld of the compiler.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of opinion whether `test1 == test2` should be supported. It's after all equal to `(test1 && test2) || (!test1 && !test2)`, which is allowed. IMO, a safe bool is a type which behaves purely as a boolean, and which therefore cannot be used in any other context. Comparison of booleans is very well defined mathematically.

Comment: @MSalters: it is less a matter of taste (or opinion) and more a matter of what are you modelling. The object you are modelling may have a different meaning for the comparison operators. Moreover, I disagree with you that `operator==` and `operator&&` are in the same level. In `(test1 && test2)`, for instance, we could extract the bool values of `test1` and `test2` first and then compare those values using the `operator&&`. I don't see the same logic applying to `operator==` just as well.

Comment: @freitass: I don't follow you. "Extract" the bool values? If that's possible, then surely you can compare those. Basically I expect "safe bool" to follow all rules of boolean algebra. `True AND False = false` is widely accepted. It requires `AND` as well as equality to be defined on booleans.

Comment: @MSalters: With "extract the bool values" I mean convert the type to bool using the "safe bool" idiom. If we implement the `operator==` as a "boolean equality", what happens to the "conventional equality"? It is not intuitive (at least for me) interpreting `test1 == test2` as "`test1` is as valid as `test2`" or "(`test1` AND `test2` are valid) OR (`test1` AND `test2` are invalid)". Is that what you are saying?

Comment: It is also wise to notice that `test1 != test2` is another way to write `test1 XOR test2`.

Comment: Allow me to repeat the other concert of mine: what happens to the concept of equality between two instances of a type implementing the "safe bool"? (The type bool do have only two states, but other types implementing "safe bool" may assume more than those two states).